# certain <img> not appearing, jquery/bootstrap carousel, only when on server

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

So I am get a strange error. On my local box the cite appears fine and all is working well. But once I uploaded it to the THC servers, the homepage slider does not show the first 4 of 7 images, there is text associated with each slide and they all work, and appear correct. 
The images are basic  tags and their src urls are all correct. I repeat that nothing has changed from my local box to the current server version.  Using Jquery and Bootstrap's carousel slider.

```
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide container" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="item active">
            <img src="images/intro/image1.jpg" alt="Chania">
            <h2 class="h2slide"> Welcome to 7cityevents.com </h2>
          </div>

          <div class="item">
            <img src="images/intro/image6.jpg" alt="Chania">
            <h2 class="h2slide"> Look For Nightlife in Your City </h2>
          </div>

          <div class="item">
            <img src="images/intro/image9.jpg" alt="Chania">
            <h2 class="h2slide"> For Food in Your CIty </h2>
          </div>

          <div class="item">
            <img src="images/intro/image10.jpg" alt="Chania">
            <h2 class="h2slide"> For Performances in Your City </h2>
          </div>

          <div class="item">
            <img src="images/intro/image12.jpg" alt="Chania">
            <h2 class="h2slide"> For Community Events in Your City </h2>
          </div>

          <div class="item">
            <img src="images/intro/image13.jpg" alt="Chania">
            <h2 class="h2slide"> Even Ways to Advance Your Career... </h2>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="images/intro/image15.png" alt="Chania">
            <h2 class="h2slide"> Select Your City Below </h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

The css and js files are all out of the box.  There seems to be no rhyme or reason to why some of these images appear and others don't especially after all is working well on my home pc.

Image: http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/0585blns04

Comment: covering the basics here, do you have your images in a folder called `images/intro/` ?

Comment: Yes, and image12.jpg, image13.jpg, and image 15.png all work as intended

Comment: what if you open `http://yoursite/images/intro/image10.jpg` in your browser? does it return 404?

Comment: Open the developer tools in Chrome. Click on the Network tab. Reload your page. Find the HTTP requests for the images in question. What's the response code for those requests (200 OK, 404 Not Found...)?

Comment: 2 different error types, the image one has 3 more matching for each image not found: http://7cityevents.com/twitter-bootstrap-v2/docs/assets/js/bootstrap-transition.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://7cityevents.com/images/intro/image1.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: you have directory listing enabled, anyway some of your files are not readable. check files permissions. http://7cityevents.com/images/intro/

Comment: FIXED: Just had to adjust permissions.